# Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

my problem is when i run the datepicker.php by it self it works fine
but when i am trying to open the page from other one ( test button)  i get this error

> Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

i think this a conflict between jquery ui to jquery mobile even do i am not loading it in the datepicker page.

first page that use jquery mobile got few buttons in it and bit of php 
one more test button:

```
<a href="datepicker.php" type=button data-theme="b" data-role="button">test</a>
```

datepicker.php:

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i allrdy try nonconflict in few ways but it didnt help:(

```
  $(function () {
var jq = $.noConflict();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) call, once you call it `$` no longer refers to jQuery.

Also it is not necessary to call it on dom ready, so try

```
//call noConflict()
var jq = $.noConflict();
//$ no longer refers to jQuery, so use the variable jQuery/jq to refer to jQuery
jQuery(function ($) {
    //the dom ready handler receices the jQuery instance as the parameter, so name it as $ so that we can use $ inside the handler to refer to jQuery
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({});
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E56af/)

Comment: i tryed that didnt help still geting the same error;/

Answer (score 0):

loading the js on ever page was the problem
only need to add it to the index header

```
<script src=..js
```

....

;/